# ON DUPLICATE KEY unrecognized in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, on-duplicate-key

I have a mysql database hosted on a remote server, I'm using InnoDB. Everything else works fine but on phpmyadmin whenever I try to execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO User (user_id, location) VALUES (1, 'London') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE location=VALUES('London')
```

It highlights `ON`, `DUPLICATE`, `KEY` because they're `unrecognized keywords`
Help please!

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `VALUES(...)` in your `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part.

```
INSERT INTO User (user_id, location) VALUES (1, 'London') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE location = 'London'
```

If you want to update more than one column, you should use normal `UPDATE` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO User (firstColumn, secondColumn) VALUES (1, 'London') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstColumn = 'ABC', secondColumn = 'DEF';
```

Comment: It works when I execute the query now, but for everybody's information, the highlighting is still the same.

Comment: The syntax highlighting error will be tracked on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11628.

Answer (score 1):

Before using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` you should add index for one or multiple column. You can use following command for adding new index.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`column1`);
```

For multiple column index use following command.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`column1`, `column2`);
```

Now you can `INSERT/UPDATE` one or more row together.

For inserting single row use following command.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`) VALUES('value1','value2','value3','value4') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column3`='value3', `column4`='value4';
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`) VALUES('value1','value2','value3','value4') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column3`=VALUES(`column3`), `column4`=VALUES(`column4`);
```

Using this command you can also `INSERT/UPDATE` multiple rows. Use following command for this purpose.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`) VALUES('value11','value12','value13','value14'),('value21','value22','value23','value24') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column3`=VALUES(`column3`), `column4`=VALUES(`column4`);
```